# (Pacman) Loading 151 dots (picturebox) in form. What's the easy way?

Tags: c#

I'm making pacman clone for school project and I'm having a bit of a struggle with loading dots into the map. I want to put 151 dots (`picturebox`) onto a map to a specific location, so that later on I could check if there is collision between Pacman and dots using function `intersectWith`.

I feel like this isn't really the most friendly way of doing it, but currently I don't have any other idea.

So, how does one put many `picturebox` on a form (if there is a way), and put them in array where I could check for intersection.

This is just some brief, probably wrong code, how I'm imagining this to work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 151; ++i)
{
    dot[i] = Resources.dot;
    drawingArea.Load(dot[i]);
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Just a little note: I removed the part about "happy new year". Although it's appropriate today, that part will not be relevant to a visitor that comes in 6 months from now. We try to make questions and answers timeless here :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that I think your code is on the right track, although knowing PACMAN I don't think you'll be able to set the positions in a loop because they're not based on a predictable pattern- you'll probably need to set them individually. One way to handle this would be to store the "level" information in a file and then loop through it to create the dots. C# isn't my first language, but the pseudo-code would look something like this:

Imagine our file looks like this: (Super small level for this example)

```
0000000
0223220
1200021
0224220
0000000
```

0 = wall, 1 = clear path, 2 = dot, 3 = ghost start, 4 = PACMAN start. You could then create your map based on the following pseudo-code:

```
string rawRows = System.file.io.ReadAllLines("some/path/to/file"); // See Article #1
for(int row = 0; row < rawRows.length; row++) { // Loop row by row (line by line)
  for(int column = 0; column < rawRows[row].length; column++) {
    switch(rawRows[row][column]) {
      case 0:
        // Add wall
      case 1:
        // Add Clear Path Image
      case 2:
        // Add Clear Path Image
        // Add Dot Image on Top
      case 3:
        // Add Clear Path Image
        // Add Ghost
      case 4:
        // Add Clear Path Image
        // Add PACMAN
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Article #1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

When you add a Dot to your game, you could put them in an array like you said, so that you can loop through it and see how many dots are remaining.

---

The better answer is that you probably shouldn't be trying to use forms and pictureboxes at all to make a game- they're not intended for this purpose, and they'll be clunky (My first game was "Checkers" using VB Forms). If your class permits it, and you're willing to put in the time and effort to learn, I recommend you look into a game framework (like [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/)) to create your game with. It'll have a steeper learning curve, but it will allow you to make a much better game overall.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have done it in the exact way, reading map from .txt file and drawing it. I'm using AABB collision for wall detecting, but I can't in any way find solution for intersecting with dots, and then not redrawing them. That's why I thought of picturebox object and method intersectWith.